# Huge distance between listview items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, space, items

I have a listview with weight sum 4. After including images, I having big padding, but I clear all margins and paddings. All data receiving via adapter from MainActivity.
There are screen shot and code below. Thanks for watching and help.

[image]

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Пн, сегодня"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cloud_queue_24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="+17"
        android:id="@+id/genre"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="+9"
        android:id="@+id/year"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post full XML code. Also post XML contains `List View`.

Comment: check my answer and use this code. let me know if you face problem. and make sure you post your code in above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try to use this code.**

> Changes i have made is added `Linear Layout` inside `Relative Layout` with `match_parent` as Height and Width. Because Linear Layout childs containing `match_parent` as height so that will affect the list items. That's why i have added new Root Layout and defined all childs as OP.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Пн, сегодня"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_dashboard" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/genre"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="+17"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/year"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="+9"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: yeah, it works, thak you. It's my code above, but i can't insert part of this.

Comment: @Downvoter shoot your Reason for `Down Vote` ? His issue is solved man !!

Comment: @jaydroider. although this solution might work, **Try this code**-answers are generally not very good answers. It might help the asker in his specific problem, but it doesn't teach the asker anything. Good answers also explain why the asker's approach doesn't work and also explain why the proposed solution does work

Comment: @IvoBeckers It's doesn't mean you `Down Vote` the answer and make the answer Quality  low which is enough good for asker to solve his problem.

Comment: @jaydroider, I disagree with you. This website is not about giving answers that are 'good enough' and also not only to help the asker. It's to help the entire community and teach people how and why stuff works. Future visitors of this question might want to know why it works. And please, don't feel offended, this is not a personal attack. You can always improve your answer and then I might upvote it

Comment: See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-very-low-quality

Comment: @IvoBeckers  Thanks for your Suggestions and Informations :).

Answer (score 0):

The `LinearLayout` the four elements are in have height `wrap_content` which basically means make it the height the children are. But all 4 children have height `match_parent` which says just fit in my parent. So this is not very compatible. What I would do is either give all 4 children height `wrap_content` also, or what maybe better is give the LinearLayout a fixed `layout_height`